# Why is my bootstrap styling not getting applied?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to Flask and Bootstrap and trying to use them together, but the styles from bootstrap don't get applied when the html is rendered, it's just plain. Specifically, the "`<div class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">`" I got from the components page of bootstrap isn't getting applied. Can someone please advise me why? I'm developing locally for now. The CSS file I was using for styling prior to this worked fine.
Thanks in advance.
My code:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>My Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class=page>
  <h1>My Page</h1>
      <div class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
    <a href="{{ url_for('main_page') }} ">home</a>  
  {% if not session.logged_in %}
    <a href="{{ url_for('login') }}">log in</a>
  {% else %}
    <a href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">log out</a>
    <a href="{{ url_for('reminders') }}">reminders</a>
  {% endif %}
    <a href="{{ url_for('about') }}">about</a>
  </div>
  {% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
    <div class=flash>{{ message }}</div>
  {% endfor %}
  {% block body %}{% endblock %}
</div>
```

Comment: add proper markup first. like `<head>..</head>` and put the `link href=''`inside  `head tag`. add `type='text/css'` in your bootstrap stylesheet as well.

Comment: you need `<body>...</body>` tag as well.

Comment: <head> and <body> tags are optional though.

Answer (score 0):

Your head tag is missing.  You need

```
<head>styles go here</head>
```

at the top right below your `<!doctype html>` tag.